# Accessing files in "solution folder" created

Tags: c#

I like to read the contents of the folder "files" which is in solution not in local machine . (which contains multiple text files. I want to get all the file names in the folder "files") .

Comment: Maybe look into the `File` class, `DirectoryInfo` class, `System.IO` namespace

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Have you tried to search for it? "c# get all the file names in the folder"

Comment: I added a folder in solution (textFiles) , which contains some .txt files. Now i want to iterate through that specific folder.

Answer (score 1):

Please see [MSDN: How To Enumerate Files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997370(v=vs.110).aspx) . Please be aware that EnumerateFiles returns a hot Enumerable. If you iterate two times, it will read the files two times. You can create a list of these files.

```
    string dirPath = @"c:\files";

    foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(dirPath))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(file)
    }
    Console.WriteLine("{0} directories found.",  dirs.Count);
```

If you really only nead the names you could also look here [MSDN Directory.GetFiles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
 string [] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(targetDirectory);

foreach(string fileName in fileEntries)
{
    Console.WriteLine(fileName);
}
```

If you want to do more then just display the names (e.g. processing the files) then EnumerateFiles would be better as you have only at a time in memory.